# BaseX 8.5: How to set the base directory of queries run through HTTP or XQJ?

Tags: xquery, basex

I have two queries in the following locations:

```
/home/myname/path/to/queries/myQuery1.xqy
/home/myname/path/to/queries/myQuery2.xqy
```

And a query module in:

```
/home/myname/path/to/xqm/myModule.xqm
```

In both queries, I import the module with the following line:

```
import module namespace myns = 'http://myns' at "../xqm/myModule.xqm";
```

The first query is run from BaseX's GUI, and it works fine.  The second query is called through BaseX's HTTP server, and also through XQJ.  However, it fails with the following message:

```
[XQST0059] Could not retrieve module: /home/xqm/myModule.xqm
```

Clearly, the base directory is being set to my home directory `/home/myname`; hence the malformed path to the module.
Apparently, the problem is that the base directory is correctly set only for queries run from the GUI, from which `file:base-dir()` returns:

```
    /home/myname/path/to/queries/
```

An absolute path for the module solves the problem, but for consistency, I prefer to use relative paths.  Is there a way to set the base directory, when calling queries through HTTP or XQJ?

EDIT: More specifically, is there a way to make XQJ and REST interfaces to resolve relative paths, just as the GUI does?  That is, resolving against the location of the query being run?  (Thanks to chrisis for helping me to better formulate the question.)

Comment: Don't think you can do this dynamically. What's wrong with just using BaseX configuration options so it's set consistently for GUI, webserver and  client/server?

Comment: @chrisis Setting option QUERYPATH in .basex produces inconsistent results between REST and XQJ.  A path that works for XQJ does not work for REST.  For some reason, REST looks for the same module file three directories above where XQJ finds it.  Besides, an option that affects all interfaces may be too extreme.  If a query wants to access a module in another place, it will be unable to do it.  It would be better to have relative paths resolved against the location of the query being run, just as it occurs in the GUI.

Comment: By the way, I found that QUERYPATH does not affect the GUI.  So, if it works for one interface, it doesn't work for the others.  Interestingly, this option does not appear in the HTML docs; only in the PDF docs.

Comment: If you look at the changelog on the HTML page it's removed for version 8.6. Not often docs are updated too quickly! I think the option you're looking for may be REPOPATH. Haven't checked it works consistently (I don't use client/server setup) but it's under General Options so looks hopeful.

Comment: @chrisis You're right! REPOPATH works. Didn't know about this "drop and forget" facility.  It makes easy to have modules available everywhere.  Although this is the closest to a solution, the question still lingers about BaseX's inconsistent treatment of the base URI.  Ironically, in the repository documentation, I found the following about library modules: _"The specified location may be absolute or relative; in the latter case, it is resolved against the location (i.e., static base URI) of the calling module."_  That's the behavior of the GUI.  Should be the same for other interfaces.